# Add product with array of options to cart

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a product. I add it to my cart.  If such an item exists in the shopping cart, I will increase its counter. It's simple, checking by id.

I have a product, it has an array of options. (milk, cream, sugar, etc.) How to check the cart, and find an existing copy of the product with such options?

```
function addCoffeeToCart(coffee: CartItem) {

    const coffeeAlreadyExistsInCart = cartItems.findIndex(
      (cartItem) => cartItem.id === coffee.id 
    );

    const newCart = produce(cartItems, (draft) => {
      if (coffeeAlreadyExistsInCart < 0) {
        draft.push(coffee);
      } else {
        draft[coffeeAlreadyExistsInCart].quantity += coffee.quantity;
      }
    });

    setCartItems(newCart);
  }
```

Product:

```
export interface Coffee {
  id: number;
  tags: string[];
  name: string;
  description: string;
  photo: string;
  price: number;
  options: Options[];
}
```

Options:

```
export interface Options{ 
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
}
```

Comment: Please add Options interface as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `coffeeAlreadyExistsInCart` to this and try again:

```js
const coffeeAlreadyExistsInCart = cartItems.findIndex(
    (cartItem) =>
        cartItem.id === coffee.id &&
        JSON.stringify(cartItem.options) === JSON.stringify(coffee.options)
);
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way of dealing with the count / if exist - is to use an object literal as a map of the existing items in the cart. Then you can have an array of the items with their salient details, and use the object literal to keep track of the count (which automatically deals with the if-exists issue) and then create a cart and a running total of the toal price etc.

The advantage of this approach is that it separates the count logic from the item details in your store and allows for different id and display... eg you can have an id of "c1234-1" and a displayText of "Coffee" and this will still allow you to have your calculartions. Its also good to separate your items details from the cart / store - so that you can easily update prices or availability etc.

Deleting items from the cart is simple - just decrement the count of the item down to 0 and this will adjust the cart total as you do so.

```js
const items = [
 {id: 'coffee', name: 'Coffee', price: 5.5},
 {id: 'tea', name: 'Tea', price: 3.5},
 {id: 'cocoa', name: 'Cocoa', price: 2.5},
 {id: 'milk', name: 'Milk', price: .5},
 {id: 'sugar', name: 'Sugar', price: 0},
]

const cartItems = {};

function addItemToCart(id) {
  cartItems[id]
    ? cartItems[id] ++
    : cartItems[id] = 1;
 
  setCart()
}
  
function setCart() {
  const cart = {total: 0, items:[]};
  
  Object.keys(cartItems).forEach(id => {
    const item = items.find(x => x.id === id);
    const itemQty = cartItems[id];
  
    cart.items.push({name: item.name, quantity: itemQty, subTotal: item.price * itemQty });
    cart.total+= (item.price * itemQty);
  })
  console.log(cart)
}
  
addItemToCart('coffee'); 
  // gives {"total": 5.5, "items": [{"name": "Coffee","quantity": 1, "subTotal": 5.5}]}

addItemToCart('coffee'); 
  // gives { "total": 11, "items": [{"name": "Coffee","quantity": 2,"subTotal": 11}]} 

addItemToCart('tea');
  // gives { "total": 14.5, "items": [{"name": "Coffee","quantity": 2,"subTotal": 11},{"name": Tea","quantity": 1,"subTotal": 3.5} ] } 

addItemToCart('milk'); 
  // gives { "total": 15, "items": [{"name": "Coffee","quantity": 2,"subTotal": 11},{"name": "Tea","quantity": 1,"subTotal": 3.5},{"name": "Milk","quantity": 1,"subTotal": 0.5} ]}}
  
addItemToCart('sugar');  
  // gives { "total": 15, "items": [{"name": "Coffee","quantity": 2,"subTotal": 11},{"name": "Tea","quantity": 1,"subTotal": 3.5},{"name": "Milk","quantity": 1,"subTotal": 0.5},{"name": "Sugar","quantity": 1,"subTotal": 0} ] }
```

Comment: I like your approach. But apparently I need time to digest the information. ) I think I need to wrap items in a new object to get a "cappuccino".

Answer (score 0):

On the condition of the findIndex you have to add that verification. As answered you can do it with Json.stringify of both arrays but that assumes they are on the same order and complety equal. I prefer to use Array.every and Array.some to ignore those constraints at cost of a little of performance.

```
const coffeeAlreadyExistsInCart = cartItems.findIndex(
(cartItem) =>
    cartItem.id === coffee.id &&
    cartItem.options.length === coffee.options.length &&
    coffee.options.every(item => cartItem.options.some(elem => elem.id === item.id))
);
```

Basically with this we are "asking" to each CartItem if they have the same number of options as coffee ( dont know if as to be like that, if you want to just check if have the all the options but not if they have the same number of options you can ignore that condition ) and if every option on the cartItem exists on teh coffee options